# How to remove the tr from table when class name(appendNoRecord) is exist other wist not removed

Tags: angularjs, keyboard-events

When user search the data, then no data related to the search text box then display "No Data Found" after clear the text box remove the "No Data Found tr". 
I am using the keyup event, if the table length is "0" then i have to append **tr** in **No Data Found** with **appendNoRecord class**, After clear the searchbox, How to remove the **tr No data Found** please help me. the below image to remove tr "No Data Found". click the below link to open the jsfiddle code

```js
 angular.module("app", [])
   .controller('filterController', ['$scope', '$document',
     function($scope, $document) {
       $scope.employees = [{
         name: "Stewart",
         age: "25",
         phoneNumber: "563544466"
       }, {
         name: "Stone",
         age: "34",
         phoneNumber: "657865856"
       }, {
         name: "Grudin",
         age: "27",
         phoneNumber: "679423435"
       }, {
         name: "Drucker",
         age: "25",
         phoneNumber: "343667789"
       }, {
         name: "Davis",
         age: "44",
         phoneNumber: "456724423"
       }, {
         name: "Crowfoot",
         age: "35",
         phoneNumber: "789345564"
       }, {
         name: "Confucius",
         age: "26",
         phoneNumber: "243567333"
       }, {
         name: "Burnett",
         age: "50",
         phoneNumber: "879344666"
       }];

       $scope.sortColumn = "name";
       $scope.reverseSort = false;

       $scope.sortData = function(column) {
         $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
         $scope.sortColumn = column;
       }

       $scope.getSortClass = function(column) {
         if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
           return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up'
         }
       }

       $scope.keySearch = function() {
         var element = angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#tablesorter'));
         var that = element.find('tbody').find('tr');
         if (that.length == 0) {
           element.find('tbody').append('<tr><td colspan="4" class="appendNoRecord" align="center" width="100%">No Records Found</td></tr>');
         } else {
           angular.forEach(that, function(value, index) {
             if (this.hasClass('appendNoRecord')) {
               debugger;
             }
           })



         }
       }
     }
   ]);

 angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```css
/*This class displays the UP arrow*/

.arrow-up {
  background: url(../Images/desc.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-color: #C7DF65;
}
/*This class displays the DOWN arrow*/

.arrow-down {
  background: url(../Images/asc.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-color: #C7DF65;
}
/*Sorting default Arrows*/

table th {
  background: url(../Images/bg.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C7DF65;
}
/*Fixed table header with scrolling tbody*/

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead > tr > th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.table > thead > tr:after,
.table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
/*Fixed table header with scrolling tbody*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="filterController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
        Search
        <input type="text" ng-model="SearchFilter" ng-keyup="keySearch()" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table  table-fixed table-striped" id="tablesorter" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-click="sortData('name')" ng-class="getSortClass('name')" class="col-xs-3">Name
          </th>
          <th ng-click="sortData('age')" ng-class="getSortClass('age')" class="col-xs-3">Age
          </th>
          <th ng-click="sortData('phoneNumber')" ng-class="getSortClass('phoneNumber')" class="col-xs-3">Phone Number
          </th>
          <th class="col-xs-3">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter: SearchFilter | orderBy: sortColumn:reverseSort">
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{ emp.name }}
          </td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{ emp.age }}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{ emp.phoneNumber }}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="Edit" />&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="Delete" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/Mittudev/0ra2chhz/12/)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Mittudev/0ra2chhz/12/  This is the link my full code. The Fiddler link is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.keySearch = function () {
                    var element = angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#tablesorter'));
                    var that = element.find('tbody').find('tr');
                    if (that.length == 0) {
                        element.find('tbody').append('<tr><td colspan="4" class="appendNoRecord" align="center" width="100%">No Records Found</td></tr>');
                    }
                    else {
                        angular.forEach(that, function (value, index) {
                            var tr = angular.element(value);
                            if (that.length > 1) {
                                if (tr.find('td').eq(0).hasClass('appendNoRecord')) {
                                    tr.remove();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a key up event here. You could use ng-if and check if the filtered list is empty or not and display it accordingly.

here is what you could do.

```js
 angular.module("app", [])
   .controller('filterController', ['$scope', '$document',
     function($scope, $document) {
       $scope.employees = [{
         name: "Stewart",
         age: "25",
         phoneNumber: "563544466"
       }, {
         name: "Stone",
         age: "34",
         phoneNumber: "657865856"
       }, {
         name: "Grudin",
         age: "27",
         phoneNumber: "679423435"
       }, {
         name: "Drucker",
         age: "25",
         phoneNumber: "343667789"
       }, {
         name: "Davis",
         age: "44",
         phoneNumber: "456724423"
       }, {
         name: "Crowfoot",
         age: "35",
         phoneNumber: "789345564"
       }, {
         name: "Confucius",
         age: "26",
         phoneNumber: "243567333"
       }, {
         name: "Burnett",
         age: "50",
         phoneNumber: "879344666"
       }];

       $scope.sortColumn = "name";
       $scope.reverseSort = false;

       $scope.sortData = function(column) {
         $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
         $scope.sortColumn = column;
       }

       $scope.getSortClass = function(column) {
         if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
           return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up'
         }
       }

     }
   ]);

 angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```css
/*This class displays the UP arrow*/

.arrow-up {
  background: url(../Images/desc.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-color: #C7DF65;
}
/*This class displays the DOWN arrow*/

.arrow-down {
  background: url(../Images/asc.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-color: #C7DF65;
}
/*Sorting default Arrows*/

table th {
  background: url(../Images/bg.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #C7DF65;
}
/*Fixed table header with scrolling tbody*/

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead > tr > th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.table > thead > tr:after,
.table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
/*Fixed table header with scrolling tbody*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="filterController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
        Search
        <input type="text" ng-model="SearchFilter" ng-keyup="keySearch()" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table  table-fixed table-striped" id="tablesorter" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-click="sortData('name')" ng-class="getSortClass('name')" class="col-xs-3">Name
          </th>
          <th ng-click="sortData('age')" ng-class="getSortClass('age')" class="col-xs-3">Age
          </th>
          <th ng-click="sortData('phoneNumber')" ng-class="getSortClass('phoneNumber')" class="col-xs-3">Phone Number
          </th>
          <th class="col-xs-3">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" ng-if="!(employees | filter: SearchFilter).length" class="appendNoRecord" align="center" width="100%">No Records Found</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter: SearchFilter | orderBy: sortColumn:reverseSort">
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{ emp.name }}
          </td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{ emp.age }}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{ emp.phoneNumber }}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="Edit" />&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" value="Delete" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```